# Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that for all $x \in G-H$ and all $y \in G$ there exist $u \in H$ such that $y^{-1}xy=u^{-1}xu$ ...

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ such that for each $x \in G-H $
and each $y \in G$, there is a $u \in H$ that $y^{-1}xy = u^{-1}xu$. Prove that $H \lhd G$,
and $G/H$ is abelian.

I saw this problem in a mathematical competition for university students in Iran. I'm completely confused. I don't know how to start. Could you please give me some hint. I'm not asking for the whole proof, a piece of hint or direction to start would be enough.

Comment: The hypothesis implies that $G \setminus H$ is a union of conjugacy classes of $G$. So the same applies to $H$ and hence $H$ is a normal subgroup. If $G/H$ were not abelian, then you could find two distinct elements of $G/H$ that were conjugate in $G/H$, and then they would have inverse images conjugate in $G$ but, since they map onto distinct elements of $G/H$, they cannot be conjugate by an element of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: First prove that $H$ is normal in $G$. Try to prove using the assumption that conjugation in $G$ sends things outside $H$ to things outside $H$, and hence must send things inside $H$ to things inside $H$.

To show that $G/H$ is abelian, try to show that in $G/H$, conjugation is trivial, and note that a group is abelian iff conjugation acts trivially in that group.

******FULL PROOF******

Note that for $h\in H$, and $g\in G$, $hgh^{-1}\in H$ iff $g\in H$. Your assumption then says that for any $x\in G - H$, $g\in G$, $gxg^{-1} = hxh^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$, but $x\notin H$, so $gxg^{-1} = hxh^{-1} \in G - H$. This shows that conjugation in $G$ sends things outside $H$ to things outside $H$, but of course this also means that it must send things inside $H$ to things inside $H$ (if it sent something in $H$ to something outside $H$, then conjugation by the inverse sends something outside $H$ to something inside $H$, which we just proved can't happen).

This shows that $H$ is normal in $G$.

Now the assumption that for any $g\in G,x\in G-H$, we have $gxg^{-1} = hxh^{-1}$ for some $h\in H$, can be viewed mod $H$, where it becomes the statement: Conjugation in $G/H$ of nontrivial elements the same as conjugating by the identity, ie, conjugation in $G/H$ of nontrivial elements is trivial. Of course, conjugating the identity by anything is trivial, so this shows that conjugation in $G/H$ is trivial. The only groups where this is true are abelian groups.

Comment: I think you have the property backwards. The element being conjugated upon is in $G-H$, but in your proof you assumed $h \in H$.

Comment: The assumption is that $y^{-1} x y = u^{-1} x u$ where $x \in G \setminus H$; what you wrote has $x \in H$..

Comment: It's confusing because the hypothesis implies that, for $g \in G$ and $h \in G \setminus H$, $g^{-1}hg \in G \setminus H$. But that's actually equivalent to $h \in H$ implies $g^{-1}hg \in H$.

Comment: Whoops, misread the question. Thanks, I've fixed it now.

Comment: Good hint and a clear proof! Thanks.